# Azure Bot NodeJS wait for other dialog to be finished

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm currently building a chatbot with Azure's Bot service. I use a NLU-Bot, mixed with a waterfall flow, because dependent on the intent I want to get some specific information.
Therefore I match the `intent1` and want to

```
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] })
.matches('intent1', (session, args, results) =>{

    session.beginDialog("getRequiredInformations");
    session.send("I received your information");
})

bot.dialog('getRequiredInformations', [
    (session) =>{       
        var levels = ['Beginner', 'Intermediate', 'Expert'];
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, "What's your level ?", levels, { listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button, maxRetries: 0 });
    },
    (session, results) => {
        session.conversationData.level = results.response.entity;
    }
]);
```

What I want to do is to wait until we received the answer from the `getRequiredInformations` dialog and then continue with the original dialog containing the recognized intent. With the code above the `session.send("I received your information");`is sent before the user entered an answer.

I also tried with `bot.beginDialogAction('getRequiredInformations', 'getRequiredInformations');` but I think it's not possible to call this inside the dialog.

How am I able to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found there several misstakes in your code snippet, please refer the following modification:

```
bot.dialog('intent1', [(session, args, next) => {
    session.beginDialog("getRequiredInformations");
}, (session, args, next) => {
    session.send("I received your information");
    session.send(session.conversationData.level)
}]).triggerAction({
    matches: 'intent1'
})

bot.dialog('getRequiredInformations', [
    (session) => {
        var levels = ['Beginner', 'Intermediate', 'Expert'];
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, "What's your level ?", levels, {
            listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button,
            maxRetries: 0
        });
    },
    (session, results) => {
        session.conversationData.level = results.response.entity;
        session.endDialog();
    }
]);
```

> But this means there is not really an opportunity to wait for the dialog to finish like a callback or anything, I need to do this with a waterfall?

If I understand correct, you can try to use the following code snippet to enable the luis recognizer only if there is no dialog in stack.

```
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(luisAppUrl)
 .onEnabled(function (context, callback) {
     var enabled = context.dialogStack().length == 0;
     callback(null, enabled);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this means there is not really an opportunity to wait for the dialog to finish like a callback or anything, I need to do this with a waterfall?

Answer (score 1):

Move the send to next waterfall step of the `intent1` dialog. I think this should work.

```
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] })
.matches('intent1', [(session, args, results) =>{

    session.beginDialog("getRequiredInformations");
}, (session, args, results) =>{
    session.send("I received your information");
}]);
```

`matches` method takes **IWaterfallStep** or **IWaterfallStep[]**. More info [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.intentdialog.html#matches).